# How does the Google Maps IPhone app notify with Bluetooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

I'm looking for some reference to how the Google Maps app is able to send turn by turn directions to in car Bluetooth systems. The reason being that my car does not support [A2DP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Advanced_Audio_Distribution_Profile_.28A2DP.29) so i haven't been able to stream my music/podcasts directly to the radio.

Google seem to be using the phone profile, otherwise known as the Hands Free Protocol- [HFP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Hands-Free_Profile_.28HFP.29), and it looks like a call on the in car radio.

If someone could point me to the API to make this happen I could potentially use this little quirk to write an app that supports streaming to my car stereo system.

Does anyone know what API this is? Or if you have example code that would be even better. This one has been a tough one to track down on Google!

Comment: I am looking for the answer as well. I have seen no other app do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

HFP is enabled by passing [AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosessioncategoryoptions/avaudiosessioncategoryoptionallowbluetooth?language=objc) to any of the `-setCategory:...options:...` methods on [AVAudioSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession?language=objc):

> You’re required to set this option to allow routing audio input and output to a paired Bluetooth Hands-Free Profile (HFP) device. If you clear this option, paired Bluetooth HFP devices don’t show up as available audio input routes.
>
> ...
>
> You can set this option only if the audio session category is AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord or AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord.